# MQTT.js multiple subscription

Tags: javascript, mqtt, iot

I'm playing around with MQTT and MQTT.js. I have running a MQTT broker and now I want to subscribe to multiple topics. One topic is no problem, but multiple.

I have these two topics:

```
'sensor/esp8266-1/humidity'
'sensor/esp8266-1/temperature'
```

and I with this piece of code I subscribe on these two topics

```
var mqtt = require('mqtt');
var client  = mqtt.connect('mqtt://10.0.0.18');


client.subscribe('sensor/esp8266-1/humidity');
client.subscribe('sensor/esp8266-1/temperature');

client.on('message', function(topic, message, packet) {
    console.log(packet)
});
```

With this code console.log returns me the following

```
Packet {
  cmd: 'publish',
  retain: false,
  qos: 0,
  dup: false,
  length: 35,
  topic: 'sensor/esp8266-1/temperature',
  payload: <Buffer 32 31 2e 32 30> }
Packet {
  cmd: 'publish',
  retain: false,
  qos: 0,
  dup: false,
  length: 32,
  topic: 'sensor/esp8266-1/humidity',
  payload: <Buffer 34 31 2e 30 30> }
```

This looks at the first very good, but how can I get the temperature/humidity data from that?

I tried it with this

```
console.log(packet.payload.toString())
```

But now I got every time temperature and humidty without which I know what number means.

In the End I would like to get two variables (temperature/humidity) fill with the right data. Later I want to concat the two variables and store these to an SQL Database.

Comment: What do you mean by "code is not very functionable." The code subscribes to 2 topics, which is exactly what you asked it to do

Comment: Also have you read the doc? It is very clear on how to subscribe to multiple topics and even offers 3 different ways to do it

Comment: Yes but I cant find something, where do you find that?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mqtt#mqttclientsubscribetopictopic-arraytopic-object-options-callback and you haven't answered the first question

Comment: Yes I have seen this, but how can I read every single payload package?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Edit your original question to make it clearer what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I think it is clear enough. I only want the Data from every Sensor as an own variable. With this code and these documentation it is not possbile to get for every topic the sensor data.

Answer (score 7):

You've not said how you want to uses these 2 values but the following is the simplest way to start.

```
var mqtt = require('mqtt');
var client  = mqtt.connect('mqtt://10.0.0.18');

var temperature;
var humidity;

client.subscribe('sensor/esp8266-1/humidity');
client.subscribe('sensor/esp8266-1/temperature');

client.on('message', function(topic, message, packet) {
  if (topic === 'sensor/esp8266-1/temperature') {
    temperature = message;
  }

  if (topic === 'sensor/esp8266-1/humidity') {
    humidity = message;
  }
});
```

You can make it a little simpler by using a single wildcard subscription:

```
client.subscribe('sensor/esp8266-1/+');
```

Which will subscribe to all topics that start with `sensor/esp8266-1/`

EDIT: 
Now we have finally thrashed out what you wanted to ask (NOT CLEAR IN THE QUESTION)

```
client.on('message', function(topic, message, packet) {
  if (topic === 'sensor/esp8266-1/temperature') {
    temperature = message;
  }

  if (topic === 'sensor/esp8266-1/humidity') {
    humidity = message;
  }

  if (temperature && humidity) {
     //do database update or print
     console.log("----");
     console.log("temp: %s", temperature);
     console.log("----");
     console.log("humidity: %s", humidity);
     //reset to undefined for next time
     temperature = undefined;
     humidity = undefined;
  }
});
```

Comment: These give me to logouts with the same data!

Comment: yes, each message is a separate event, there is no way to get all the data at once. It's not how MQTT works

Comment: Ok, than is that the problem, now I will do this on the Rest API way...

Comment: You could send both values in one message from your device

Comment: Or you can put a test in the `on('message')` callback to see if you have both values, then update the database